# Perl simple regex uppercase words separated by underscore

Tags: regex, perl

Consider I have string like `print_this_text_in_camel_case` and I want to uppercase the first word and every word after the underscore, so the result will be `Print_This_Text_In_Camel_Case`. The below test does not work on the first word.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $str = "print_this_text_in_camel_case";

$str =~ s/(_.)/uc($1)/ge;

print $str, "\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify the regex to match the first char as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $str = "print_this_text_in_camel_case";

$str =~ s/(_.|^.)/uc($1)/ge;

print $str, "\n";
```

will print out:

```
Print_This_Text_In_Camel_Case
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a beginning-of-string anchor as an alternative to the underscore.

For Perl 5.10+, I'd use a `\K` (keep) escape to emulate variable-width look-behind and only uppercase the letter. I'd also use use `\U` to perform the uppercase in the replacement text instead of `uc` and the `/e` (eval) modifier.

```
$str =~ s/(?:^|_)\K(.)/\U$1/g;
```

If you're using an older version of Perl (without `\K`) you could do it this way:

```
$str =~ s/(^|_)(.)/$1\U$2/g;
```

Another alternative is using `split` and `join` instead of a regex:

```
$str = join '_', map { ucfirst } split /_/, $s;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is tidiest to use a negative look-behind. This code fragment upper-cases all letters that aren't preceded by a letter.

```
my $str = "print_this_text_in_camel_case";

$str =~ s/ (?<!\p{alpha}) (\p{alpha}) /uc $1/xgei;

print $str, "\n";
```

**output**

```
Print_This_Text_In_Camel_Case
```

If you prefer, or if you have a very old copy of Perl that doesn't support Unicode properties, you can use `[a-z]` instead od `\p{alpha}`, like this

```
$str =~ s/ (?<![a-z]) ([a-z]) /uc $1/xige;
```

which produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [ucfirst](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html)

```
use feature 'say';

my $str = "print_this_text_in_camel_case";

my @split = map(ucfirst, (split/(_)/, $str));

say @split;
```